# How to make an element sticky to both bottom and top of page using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make an element sticky such that it "sticks" to both the top of the page if the user scrolls past it, and to the bottom of the page before the user scrolls to it.

I understand how to make it sticky in one way, but not both

Comment: Change the class on scroll

Comment: And your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself by slightly augmenting [this solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201327/trick-circumvents-position-sticky-restriction-to-parent)

HTML (unchanged):

```
BEFORE
<div class="hold">
  <div class="item">
    THING
  </div>
</div>
AFTER
```

CSS:

```
.hold {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -2000px;
  margin-bottom: -2000px; /* Added this line */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hold:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2000px;
}

/* Added the following block */ 

.hold:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2000px;
}


.item {
  pointer-events: initial;
  position: sticky;
  top:0; /* Made this addition */
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```